Cable tester indicates all lights on remote but only half on master?
I have one of those simple cable testers and I'm trying to understand what Im seeing.
Trying several spare cables I have to get a feel for the results.
Regardless of which end of the cable is plugged into the "Remote", all the lights will sequence on the remote but only lights 5 - 8 will light on the master. Could I have a bad tester? I doubt it.
On a cable I know has issues, the remote skips light 3 and the master lights only 6-8.


Test with a good known cable, like a new patch cord, and if the lights all don't light in sequence then the tester is defective. These are simple continuity testers and do nothing more than put a small voltage on each conductor and look for it at the other end, lighting an LED to indicate the circuit is complete. As a network engineer I carry one like this (from a more reputable brand) and rarely use it as the basic continuity test pretty much only tells you the cable isn't damaged enough that wire broke and the connector(s) have the wired in the correct locations, not usability.
